# Intern 4: Unable to execute tests suite

Tags: node.js, npm, intern

I use Intern 4.0 (Yes! i know! it's an alpha version. But I want rewrite my code and unit tests in es6).

I installed the npm package "intern 4.0.0-alpha.4", I rewrited code, unit tests, and suite in es6.

But i'm unable to run tests.
I want run tests from the npm scripts : I edited my `package.json` file to get:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/intern"
}
```

I 'm also tried with :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/intern config=intern.json"
}
```

or with the inter-cli :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "intern run --config intern.json"
}
```

Then i run the command `npm run test`

Here the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@4.4.4
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~pretest: myproject@0.0.1
6 silly lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~pretest: no script for pretest, continuing
7 info lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: myproject@0.0.1
8 verbose lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: PATH: ...
10 verbose lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: CWD: D:\Temp\myproject
11 silly lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'intern config=intern.json' ]
12 silly lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle myproject@0.0.1~test: Failed to exec test script
14 verbose stack Error: myproject@0.0.1 test: `intern config=intern.json`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid myproject@0.0.1
16 verbose cwd D:\Temp\myproject
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
19 verbose node v6.10.3
20 verbose npm  v4.4.4
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error myproject@0.0.1 test: `intern config=intern.json`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the myproject@0.0.1 test script 'intern config=intern.json'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myproject package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     intern config=intern.json
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs myproject
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls myproject
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "intern"
}
```

Because `intern` is a bin script in `node_modules/.bin`, you don't need to use `node_modules/.bin` in `package.json`.

Just to verify, you can try running

```
node node_modules\.bin\intern
```

Intern should run the suites you have configured in `intern.json`.

Comment: Yes, i use this with the `4.0.0-alpha.5`. But `npm run test` fails with `Feature "object-assign" exists and overwrite not true.`. I tried without tests  suite and i have the same error. I don't find why!

Comment: That sounds more like a problem loading the test runner rather than your suites in particular. What does your `intern.json` look like? What does intern do if you remove your `intern.json` and then run it?

Comment: Only : `{
 "plugins": "node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js",
 "suites": "tests/unit/test.js"
}` I have the same error whatever the content of intern.json file